# Field quanta- infinite in extent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [confusion on quantum field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50015/confusion-on-quantum-field-theory)

Are field quanta infinite in extent as stated in Art Hobsons paper? What does this even mean? I've not seen any electrons or atoms that are infinite in size?

Am I getting something wrong somewhere?

Comment: he also says there energy is sometimes spread over light years? huh

Comment: Perhaps you should edit/update your earlier question ([Confusion on quantum field theory](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50015/confusion-on-quantum-field-theory)) instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 1):

According to QM, it is the probability amplitude who is "extended", not the observation point on a screen.

Comment: so its the probability amplitude of the field quanta thats extended to infinite? not that the actual electron(field quanta) is infinite in size? Art Hobson clearly says the energy is spread over light years, what does this mean?

Comment: vladimar are you sure your not getting confused with QM by itself? this question is in regards to QFT and a field quanta being infinite in size.

Comment: Field quanta can be put made into arbitrary wavepackets, just like in QM.

Comment: @MichaelBrown wavepackets of probability waves, no?

Comment: I was thinking something like $ \left|\Psi\right> = \int \mathrm{d}^d x f(x) \hat{\phi}^\dagger(x) \left|0\right>$, where $\hat{\phi}$ is a field and $f(x)$ is the spatial wavefunction. (Assuming free fields for simplicity.)