# re-defining the question, field quanta size in field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [confusion on quantum field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50015/confusion-on-quantum-field-theory)

I asked are field quanta infinite in extent and I keep getting back that its the probabibility distribution. But this is a normal quantum mechanics answer. In terms of quantum field theory, what is meant by saying a field quanta of an electron field is infinite in extent? does it mean the quanta is infinite in size? Art Hobson has said its energy can be spread across light years which surely means the field quanta of the field is massive in size?

if we assume the wavefunction is real and doesn't collapse then each quanta is a wave spread across the whole of space, correct?

Comment: I know the question is similar but I have asked a new bit at the end, about if the wavefunction is real and doesnt collapse is a field quanta extended accross all of space, an answer to this, as with my original question would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Links to the earlier questions: [Confusion on quantum field theory](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50015/confusion-on-quantum-field-theory) and [Field quanta- infinite in extent?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50020/field-quanta-infinite-in-extent). I still think you shouldn't ask pretty much the same question 3 times in one hour.

Comment: im sorry wont happen again. I have altered it slightly

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: quantum field theory is not divorced from quantum mechanics. Any mathematical solutions pertaining to wave functions are probability wave descriptions.

See this [simplified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_theory_%28physics%29#Quantum_fields) description:

> it is possible to approach their quantum counterparts from a purely mathematical view using similar techniques as before. The equations governing the quantum fields are in fact PDEs (more precisely, relativistic wave equations (RWE)s). Thus one can speak of Yang-Mills, Dirac, Klein-Gordon and Schroedinger fields as being solutions to their respective equations. A possible problem is that these RWEs can deal with complicated mathematical objects with exotic algebraic properties (e.g. spinors are not tensors, so may need calculus over spinor fields), but these in theory can still be subjected to analytical methods given appropriate mathematical generalization.

PDE=Partial Differential Equation.

QFT uses equations for defining the wave functions that are relativistically correct.

There is no way out of it. There are no "matter waves" and whoever says so is wrong.

Comment: Anna that has not answered my question, are field quanta of a field infinite in size and what does he mean by saving there energy is spread out over light years...

Comment: and "if we assume the wavefunction is real and doesn't collapse then each quanta is a wave spread across the whole of space, correct?" whats the answer please?

Comment: Forget about "him", ( you have not given a link). This is elementary quantum mechanics. It has differential equations the solutions squared describe the probability of finding a particular quantum in a specific (x,y,z,t)  space time point. These solutions sometimes have a sinusoidal variation in space , but for finite boundaries . For infinite boundaries the square of the solutions which give the real probability, will be exponentially small,  unmeasurable. The only real thing in the mathematical analogue of reality is the probability distribution. That is where mathematics and reality meet.

Comment: anna so field quanta are not infinite in extended in space then? but you said the probability is small, so they could be...

Comment: http://physics.uark.edu/hobson/pubs/11.10.TPT.pdf      "each quantum is an energy increment of the entire space filling field"

Comment: It is two different things: The quantum itself is not spread out from here to infinity. The usual quanta have a probability of appearing whole at an (x,y,z,t) given by the solution of the appropriate relativistic equation for the boundary problem. Most of our studies happen within a radius of fermi, where interactions occur and scatterings are studied. These verify the probabilistic nature of the problem. Now if one takes a single quantum, an electron and solves with boundary conditions infinity, there will be an infinitessible probability

Comment: "Quanta that are superpositions of  different  frequencies can be more  spatially 
bunched and in this sense more localized, but they are always of infinite extent" from: http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1204/1204.4616.pdf

Comment: That if you go to infinity you might find this particular quantum, except it will be so small it will be 0 to all intents and purposes.

Comment: oh thanks. what does he mean then that the" energy of the quantum is spread out over light years" and "implies that a single mode's spatial 
dependence is sinusoidal and fills all space, so that adding a  monochromatic 
quantum to a field uniformly increases the  entire field's energy  (uniformly 
distributed  throughout all space!)"?

Comment: I must say anna, you have been a great help so far, thankyou :)

Comment: if you look at the double slit diagram in :http://physics.uark.edu/hobson/pubs/11.10.TPT.pdf - this shows that he thinks the actual electron is spread as a field and goes through both slits, is he wrong or is this an interpretation only?

Comment: I looked through your link . It is his opinion and it is wrongm imo. for example he still thinks that the two slit experiment says that the particle is spread out. It is not true, New experiments manage to identify the slit the electron went through and still there is interference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_slit_experiment#With_particle_detectors_at_the_slits . Clearly it is a probabilistic quantum world.

Comment: as for these comments anna? "energy of the quantum is spread out over light years" and "implies that a single mode's spatial dependence is sinusoidal and fills all space, so that adding a monochromatic quantum to a field uniformly increases the entire field's energy (uniformly distributed throughout all space!)"?

Comment: @lee hudson I've tried to answer that in your original question.  I'm still not sure I accept the interpretation of those trajectory pictures anna was referring to.  I haven't studied the experiment in detail, but I believe they're weak measurements, and the pictures represent some sort of average trajectory.  I might have to ask a question to clarify this.

Comment: IMO it is his own personal view and wrong. Maybe you should find another article to read. I am sorry but the field theory course I took was back in 1963 and I do not have a recent link.

Comment: @twistor59, I have put an update on my question. its a laymans question...

Comment: anna v and twistor59:, if the wavefunction doesnt collapse and is physically real, are field quantum actually spread over all of space?(assuming MWI) if these facts are true or not is not my arguement, but if they are, are the field quanta spread accross all space?

Answer (score 1):

Position is not an observable in quantum field theory; as explained in textbooks and papers $x$ in quantum field theory is an *dummy parameter without physical meaning*.

Asking about the position, size, or extension of "*field quanta*" is meaningless in quantum field theory.

As said in your other question, the article by Art Hobson is full of misconceptions and mistakes.

No, we cannot assume that the wavefunction is real:

1. The wavefunctions of quantum mechanics are not waves but unobservable functions.
2. Wavefunctions are not even defined in ordinary space
3. Quantum field theory does not use wavefunctions; that is why the Dirac and Klein Gordon equations of relativistic quantum mechanics had to be reinterpreted as mathematical identities for field operators.

Comment: as I said though, supposing the wavefunction is real and doesnt collapse(just supposing these are true) are the field quanta literally spread everwhere

Comment: any answer juanrga or anyone else?

Comment: @leehudson you cannot suppose "_real_" something that does not exist physically. The question about the "_field quanta_" was already answered above.

Comment: but thats your opinion, mwi says it is real, so the question was under mwi, are they spread infinitely everywhere?

Comment: @leehudson It is not an opinion but a basic fact explained in virtually any textbook on Quantum Mechanics. MWI has been proven wrong many times... in any case you continue ignoring what I have said about quantum field theory.